# Looking for a family of random variables such that only the second clause is fulfilled

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, integration, stochastic-calculus

Working with the epsilon-delta-criterium, a family $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ on $(\Omega,A,P)$ is uniformly integrable if

i) $sup_{i \in I} E(X_i) <\infty$

ii) $\forall \epsilon>0$ ex. $\delta>0$ s.t. $P(A)<\delta \Rightarrow \int_{A} |X_i|dP < \epsilon $

I easily came up with an example where i) is fulfilled, but ii) isn't ($X_n=1_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]} \cdot n$).

But I am looking for an example where ii) is fulfilled but i) isn't.

I would be really happy if someone had an answer because it would help me understand why we need (i).

Comment: What are you taking the supremum of in (i)?  Anyway, any example that satisfies (i) can easily be modified not to do so without breaking (ii).  This is not research level.

Comment: Let $\Omega$ be a single point having probability 1.  Then (ii) is trivially satisfied because for any $\delta < 1$, the only $A$ with $P(A) < \delta$ is $A=\emptyset$.  So now you can choose any family which violates (i), e.g. $X_n = n$.

Comment: I believe that if $\Omega$ is atomless, then (ii) implies (i).

Comment: Thank you @NateEldredge for the good example!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @NateEldredge: Let Ω be a single point having probability 1. Then (ii) is trivially satisfied because for any δ<1, the only A with P(A)<δ is A=∅. So now you can choose any family which violates (i), e.g. Xn=n.